# JSP page could't be displayed on spring boot embedded undertow

Tags: spring, maven, jsp, tomcat, undertow

I wanted to diaplay a JSP page in spring boot appliaction. I was able to to do it in tomcat but when I changed the embedded server to undertow it throws errors. I couldn't figure out why is it not working in Undertow I have changed and removed the dependencies from tomcat to undertow, I think there might be a dependency missing. Can someone point the mistake I am making here? when I run in it in undertow it throws errors as,

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers.
```

Only difference I make is in the pom.xml file.

pom.xml for Tomcat

```
<!-- Web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Web with Tomcat + Embed -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

pom.xml for Undertow

```
<!-- DEPLOY TEST -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.undertow/undertow-jsp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
    <artifactId>undertow-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Alpha21</version>
</dependency>
```

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Branch As a Service</h1>
    <form method="post" action="save">
        Name: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <p></p>
        Version: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="version"><br>
        <p></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

ServiceController.java

```
@RequestMapping("index")
  public ModelAndView viewemp(){
    return new ModelAndView("index");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations)

> Undertow does not support JSPs.

JSPs are quite old and limited (at least in Spring Boot), you should consider using a modern support templating library like Thymeleaf, FreeMarker, etc..